# Reactor EventBus shared between two or more spring boot app

Tags: spring, asynchronous, spring-boot, reactor

I have two spring-boot applications.
Reactor event-bus works correctly on single app.
How can I establish a connection between two apps through reactor event bus? Publisher and cunsumer not communicate with each other.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario, better to use MQ as the middleware to communicate between these two applications